# Python plotly + dash: Add url link to Bar Chart Sections

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to be able to add links to **each section on my bar chart** using `plotly` + `dash`.

I understand that I can add links to the bars in the chart.  I cannot, however, add links to each **section** within the bar chart.  When I try to add links to individual sections of the bar chart, all of the links per bar are stacked on top of each other.

[image: here is an example bar chart with sections]

Comment: can you include the code you've tried so far?